# How to style dynamic HTML element using CSS sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project, I created a dynamic HTML element like this one: https://codepen.io/JiveDig/pen/jbdJXR. As they have the same class name, only the first input color changes. So I decided to increment the class name of the HTML element (or id, whatever) like that

```
modsb.classList.add("switch-field" + i)
```

but how to consider this change in CSS? Is there a way to change CSS name like that

```
.switch-field${i}   or .switch-field#i
```

Or should I only style HTML elements dynamically too?

Comment: have you tried to use  @for loop ? [sass-dynamic-class]( https://ashleemboyer.com/blog/how-to-dynamically-create-many-similar-css-classes-with-sass), or use Cascading CSS Selectors

Comment: No, @for loop could  be good, but I can't use sass in the project (Palantir Slate), only css. I'm going to try with Cascading CSS Selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of naming your switch-fields like this :

```
modsb.classList.add("switch-field" + i)
```

You should name them like that :

```
modsb.classList.add("switch-field", "sf" + i)
```

Like this you can change properties for all of them using `.switch-field` or for a specific one with `.switch-field.sf2`

```css
.switch-field {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field input {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field.sf1 input:checked + label {
    background-color: red;
    
}

.switch-field.sf2 input:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-field sf1">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-one-one" name="switch-one" value="yes" checked/>
        <label for="radio-one-one">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-one-two" name="switch-one" value="no" />
        <label for="radio-one-two">No</label>
</div>

<div class="switch-field sf2">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-two-one" name="switch-two" value="yes" checked/>
        <label for="radio-two-one">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-two-two" name="switch-two" value="no" />
        <label for="radio-two-two">No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that what I'm looking for. I tried with Selector like `div[class^="switch-field"] ` but that didn't not work

Comment: Otherwise, `modsb.classList.add("switch-field sf" + i)` didn't work, but `modsb.classList.add("switch-field", "sf" + i)`

Comment: oh yes mb, i'm going to edit my answer, thanks for the correction